# setup and installation issue

Tags: c#, deployment, setup-deployment

how to resume installation after restarting pc in c# in Setup and Deployment project?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a registry entry indicating where your installer left off.
2. Make an entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce with your installer name and location.
3. Your installer will be run after the PC reboots.
4. Read the registry entry and continue your installation.

Comment: :Suppose,i have an exe to be install while installing my application.So, here i want to check whether my exe is already installed or not(it may installed manually or using this setup).If it is already installed,no need to install my exe.Otherwise,Install it.Please guide me to get this issue...

Comment: @Saravanan: That is a separate issue and has no place in this post.  If I were you, I would ask that question publicly.  Its simple, though.  You just have to check for the existence of the file where you would be installing it.